# Can you charge a LI-PO battery using negative voltage?

Tags: battery-charging, energy-harvesting

I have to charge a *LI-PO Battery* (**11.1V** 1800MAh LB-12 19.98Wh 5C) using an *P2110B* (RF Harvester). The battery charger (*YT-0003S*) supplies **12.6V @ 1.1A**.

The *P2110B* supplies only up to **5.5V** at **50mA**. Now, I know the low current will just make it charge super slow, which is ok. However, the low voltage will not work; I need at least 11.2V to charge the battery.

To pump up the voltage using little power, I wanted to use a switch-capacitor system with an Arduino and some MOSFETs. Charging multiple capacitors and then discharging them at the battery. However, there is this chip called ***LM2682*** that can take up **5.8Vin** and output up to **-11.6V**.

My questions are, can I use this negative voltage to charge my battery? Should I make a system to charge capacitors? Will the LM2682 overcharge the battery?

Comment: Why waste energy on an Arduino, when there are efficient IC's for upconversion? Also, consider the current will be somewhat less than half that 50 mA.

Comment: That chip implements a voltage inverter followed by a voltage doubler. There are other chips in that series that have only the doubler, which would be easier and more efficient if you don't need a negative voltage.